# Can men wear nylon socks in Islam?

Tags: clothing

Are men allowed to wear nylons such as nylon socks/ pantyhose in Islam ? These are usually made of synthetic fabrics such as polyester and nylons, which are not pure silk (which is, as far as I know,forbidden in Islam). Therefore,is wearing them permissible?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. Why shouldn't wearing nylon be permissible elaborate and see [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah ; In islam by default everything is halal except what is haram;

So by default it's permissible to wear nylon socks ; not made out of silk